# Как удалить первую цифру из числа?

Tags: c#

У меня, например, есть число 2179, как я могу удалить цифру 2, чтобы получить 179 ?

Comment: Число знаков может быть любое? Или всегда четырехзначные числа?

Comment: Число знаков может быть любое

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Код тупо делает то что вы написали:

```
int x = 2179;
int y = int.Parse(x.ToString().Remove(0, 1));
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

Возможно, более эффективный метод, чистая математика без преобразования в строку:

```
int x = 2179;
int p = 1;
while (x / p > 9) p *= 10;
int y = x % p;
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

Comment: А если мне нужно будет пройтись в цикле по всему числу и каждый раз уберать по одному числу ?

Comment: Выгоднее пойти вторым путем (способом ) и вычислить p один раз. Затем на каждой итерации просто делим p на 10.